# Align right modal drop down in React Native using 'react-native-modal-dropdown'

Tags: reactjs, react-native, modal-dialog, dropdown, justify

I have a code showing a dropdown in React Native using 'react-native-modal-dropdown'

```
  <View style = {{alignItems:'center',}}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress = {()=>{this.dropDown && this.dropDown.show();}}>
           <View style = {{width:170,height:40, alignItems:'center',flexDirection:'row'}}>
              <ModalDropdown ref={(el) => {this.dropDown = el}}
              options={["A", "B", "C"]}
              defaultValue = {"A"}
                             style = {{ flex: 1}}
                             textStyle = {{fontWeight:'bold', textAlign: 'right'}}
                             onSelect = {(index,value)=>{this.onClickDropDown(value)}}
                             dropdownStyle={{width:170, }}
                             renderRow={this._dropdown_renderRow.bind(this)}
              />
               <Text>▼</Text>
            </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
   </View>
```

The result is the dropdown showing behind "A": [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IbcCE.png)

I want the dropdown show the behind "▼", it justify right.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DsGST.png)

Can you help me? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress = {()=>{this.dropDown && this.dropDown.show();}}>
    <View style = {{height:40, alignItems:'center',flexDirection:'row'}}>
        <ModalDropdown ref={(el) => {this.dropDown = el}}
        options={["A", "B", "C"]}
        defaultValue = {"A"}
                        style = {{ flex: 1,paddingRight:30}}
                        textStyle = {{fontWeight:'bold', textAlign: 'right'}}

                        dropdownStyle={{width:170, }}

        />
        <View style={{ position: "absolute", right: 10, top: 10 }}><Text>▼</Text></View>
    </View>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged. Please take the time to **explain** what and *why* this solves the problem!